# JavaScript circling line

Tags: javascript, html, line

I want to make a circle line but it makes a black field. What am I missing?

here is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j6y5f7xb/1/

My code:

```
var x = 0;

var maxLoops = 800;
var counter = 0;

function loop(){
    if (counter++ >= maxLoops) return;

    var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 800, 500);

    ctx.moveTo(400,250);
    ctx.lineTo(x,100);
    ctx.stroke();

    x++;

    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log(counter);
        loop();
    }, 10);
}
loop();
```

Comment: can u provide a js fiddle?

Comment: Are you intentionally trying to draw a circle using lots of straight lines? Or do you just want a simple circle?

Comment: i just added a jsfiddle i want that there is only a line that moves to the other side of the screen. not a black thing.

Comment: I rolled your change back - someone had kindly put an inline working example and you removed it. Also " i want that there is only a line that moves to the other side of the screen" - that's not a "circle" then

Comment: Why do you not allow the snippet? It is better to have working code here than elsewhere.

Comment: you are always drawing a line from 400:250 to x:100, the result is a triangle filled with lines, as expected, could you clarify what you want to do?

Comment: no it has to be like a clock just one line that makes a circle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to add it like this
              ctx.beginPath();
              ctx.moveTo(400,250);
              ctx.lineTo(x,100);
              ctx.stroke();

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this line under the ctx.lineTo().

```
  context.fillStyle = 'black';
  context.fill();
```

For more information, you can check this site: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-circles/

Answer (score 1):

A 'circling' line like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/yucn1h2q/)?

You can't make a circle if your `y` coordingate is constant `100`

Comment: no it has to be like a clock just one line that makes a circle